# Composite key in where condition - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I'm involved in some data cleaning activities. My table does not have any unique identifier. So I decided to take 3 columns and make the index like below:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ISFTX]
ADD CONSTRAINT ISFTX_UNQ UNIQUE (IDNO,ACCTNUM,PANNO)
```

After altering table, a part of my alter script looks like this:

```
   CONSTRAINT [ISFTX_UNQ] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
  (
[IDNO] ASC,
[ACCTNUM] ASC,
[PANNO] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want to use the combination of 3 columns as ONE KEY and put it in where condition so that I can search for other column values in the same table using this where condition(ONE KEY). How can I do this?

I would prefer any example of "Where" condition and this will help? OR Please suggest me any better way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. A sample `WHERE` condition is `WHERE IDNO=1 AND ACCTNUM=2 AND PANNO=3`

Comment: Are you trying to find values that are not unique and "bad" before you apply the new key ?  Are you looking for a preliminary query like this ...   SELECT IDNO, ACCTNUM, PANNO, COUNT(ACCTNUM) FROM ISFX GROUP BY  IDNO, ACCTNUM, PANNO  HAVING COUNT(ACCTNUM) > 1

Comment: Modified my question. Hope it's understandable.